# $("#Id option") giving duplicate values

Tags: jquery

My DDL(drop-down list) contains 10 elements(including `-- Select --`).

[image: drop down list]

1.**Scenario - 1**

When I use the following `$` selection - `$("#SelectId option");` it returns an array with twice the number of elements actually present in it (other half is duplicate).

2.**Scenario - 2**

Where as, on using `$("#SelectId").find("option");` gives me the exact number of elements.

[image: console]

Why so?

**EDIT**

***As pointed out by @AlivetoDie***

I had this hidden element with the same id.

`$("#RoleId option")` was covering the entire document.
Where as `$("#RoleId").find("option")` was only getting the first selected element.

Thanks @AlivetoDie for pointing it out.

My bad, I didn't see the hidden element.

***As requested by @David Thomas***

```
<select data-cs-url="" data-optional-val="-- Select --" data-preselectedvalues="[-1]" data-unique="a0d4311ab42f47ef935543f8e3227a20" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Role must be a number." data-val-required="Select Role!" id="RoleId" name="RoleId">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="4">a - </option>
<option value="1">Admin - Administrator</option>
<option value="1004">Asp.Net Mvc Developer - Web Developer</option>
<option value="2">Data Entry - Operator</option>
<option value="3">Data Entry East - Operator For East Region</option>
<option value="1006">Data Entry2 - Operator</option>
<option value="1008">Test - Testing purpose</option>
<option value="1007">Tester - To test the application</option>
<option value="1005">Training - for training only</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am not expert in jQuery - what does `.get()` do in your code? Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: Please add you html code, else we dont much of a chance of helping you

Comment: from where `get()` is coming?

Comment: @Satpal I have made the edit

Comment: inspect your html in browser and see what html is being rendered

Comment: @AlivetoDie I don't fully understand your question?

Comment: Are you sure that the select element is rendered only once?

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML of your `<select>` element, not a screenshot of the DOM. @AlivetoDie: [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is a method which turns the jQuery object into a native JavaScript/DOM Array.

Comment: I think this has something to do with your space in `$('SelecID option');`. Try `$('SelectID', ' option');` which is actually equivalent to `$("#SelectId").find("option");`

Comment: Answer the questions about `.get` what does it do? I think that is your problem - if you remove it do you get the correct length for the array?

Comment: @Ray: no it isn't, that's equivalent to `$('option').find('#RoleId')`; you've reversed the context and the selector.

Comment: Use only $("#RoleId option").length; It returns 10 output  with include -- Select --

Comment: show us your `html` `$("#SelectId option").length` and `$('#SelectId').find('option').length` both will return 10

Comment: Possible cause:- same select-box coming twice , same id used twice, or may be some jquery code is adding some more options in background.

Comment: You are correct @DavidThomas! It must be `$('option', 'SelectID');`

Comment: I think he clearly has a duplicate of the Select, check this example i made http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdKROy

Comment: @AlivetoDie You are absolutely right. I got it.

Comment: @barnes  what you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's working fine (both scenario):-

```js
console.log($("#RoleId option").get().length); 
console.log($("#RoleId").find("option").get().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-cs-url="" data-optional-val="-- Select --" data-preselectedvalues="[-1]" data-unique="a0d4311ab42f47ef935543f8e3227a20" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Role must be a number." data-val-required="Select Role!" id="RoleId" name="RoleId">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="4">a - </option>
  <option value="1">Admin - Administrator</option>
  <option value="1004">Asp.Net Mvc Developer - Web Developer</option>
  <option value="2">Data Entry - Operator</option>
  <option value="3">Data Entry East - Operator For East Region</option>
  <option value="1006">Data Entry2 - Operator</option>
  <option value="1008">Test - Testing purpose</option>
  <option value="1007">Tester - To test the application</option>
  <option value="1005">Training - for training only</option>
</select>
```

***Note:-***

Possible cause of error at your end:-

same select-box coming twice

select-box id is repeating

some jquery code is adding some more options in background silently.

***You can use `length` directly also:-***

```js
console.log($("#RoleId option").length); 
console.log($("#RoleId").find("option").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-cs-url="" data-optional-val="-- Select --" data-preselectedvalues="[-1]" data-unique="a0d4311ab42f47ef935543f8e3227a20" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Role must be a number." data-val-required="Select Role!" id="RoleId" name="RoleId">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="4">a - </option>
  <option value="1">Admin - Administrator</option>
  <option value="1004">Asp.Net Mvc Developer - Web Developer</option>
  <option value="2">Data Entry - Operator</option>
  <option value="3">Data Entry East - Operator For East Region</option>
  <option value="1006">Data Entry2 - Operator</option>
  <option value="1008">Test - Testing purpose</option>
  <option value="1007">Tester - To test the application</option>
  <option value="1005">Training - for training only</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I had a hidden element with the same id.